# What is the best way to store highscores?

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am developing an application which contains quiz, but in the end user gets the exact percentage of responses to the quiz, where I want to be the final score.

which is the best way to storing results?

`SQLitedatabase` or `SharedPreferences` and how?

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int score= b.getInt("score");
bar.setRating(score);
```

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one scalar value You wish to store go with [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref),
for ranking I recommend simple table in [SQLitedatabase](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

If by presentation, you actually meant "**way of storing**", that depends on what you want to store.

If you just want to save a quick score, `SharedPreferences` should be a fast and sufficient way to do so. However, I am quite sure you also want to store the players name that scored the highscore, maybe a date and some other parameters. In that case, **I definitely recommend** using a local (or remote) **SQL Database**.

The `SQL Database` provides quick access to stored data and is in general a very good way of storing larger amounts data.

Comment: More details, please?